# I can't submit form to server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have created a login form and trying to submit it using jquery but it doesn't work.I have searched google but all methods are a bit complicated.Here is my code

```
<form id="form1">
<p>Username<p/>
<input type="text" id="username"/>
<p>Password</p>
<input type="password" id="password"/>
<p><input type="Submit" value="Log in" id="button"></p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

$("#button").click(function(){

var username=$("#username").val();
var password=$("#password").val();

$.get("signing.php",{'username':username,'password':password},function(response){
alert(response);
});

});

</script>
```

My php file is like this

```
<?php

session_start();

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

include 'model/existusername.php';//This is used to connect to database and find the user

if (existusername($username,$password))
{
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
echo "loged in";  
}
else
{
echo "not loged in"; 
}

?>
```

Is there something wrong with it?If I use a select box(although not useful for loging in) instead of input box the code works fine.How is that possible??
Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the error console in Firefox, Chrome or Safari bowser?

Comment: Yes it doesn't give any errors

Comment: Check the network tab of your developer tools.  What is the response you get?

Comment: What should I be looking in the network tab?

Comment: When you have the network tab open, click the "Log In" button in your form.  If the get request is being triggered, it will show up in this list.  Typically, the status should be 200, and the response should be "loged in" or "not loged in".  Since it hasn't been working, either it won't show up at all, or you'll see an error.

Comment: For my html and js file the status is 200. But the php file doesn't show up in the list. Any suggestion what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your method to look like this:

```
$("#button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    // ...
});
```

Alternatively, use a button input that won't cause a submission.

```
<input type="button" value="Log in" id="button">
```

Since the button is a submit button, the page is performing a form submission before the GET response arrives.  Prevent the submission from happening, and your code should work.

Comment: You are right. Both methods work. So if I got it wright, the form is submitted nowhere and that cancels the GET request??So you can't have a submission of a form and GET request together?

Comment: A form will submit to the current page if no action is specified.  Since your GET request was asynchronous, the browser gave priority to completing the form submission and cancelled your request.  The submission caused a navigation back to a fresh copy of the current page, obscuring what happened.  Secondly, you can delay a form submission until after an AJAX request is completed, but in your case that's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You are using $.get() which sends a get request with jquery.

Your php file is checking the $_POST vars.

Comment: I changed the $_POST to $_GET but still it is not working.Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Add an "action=" on your form, and after something like that :

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  $('#form').submit();
});
```

No ?

And you are using GET and try to recover POST..i think it's not normal.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="pathToYourPhpScript">
 <p>Username<p/>
 <input type="text" id="username"/>
 <p>Password</p>
 <input type="password" id="password"/>
 <p><input type="Submit" value="Log in" id="button"></p>
</form>
```

You have to remember to select the method, and proberbly the action in the form start tag.

as standard the data is sent through a GET request, and you are trying to read from a post.

The example i have provided is with no AJAX, but again, if you wanna make it work with the ajax, you have to alter your javascript to do a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        cache:false,
                        async:true,
                        url: "index.php",   
                        data: $('#id').serialize(),                         
                        success: function(data){
                            alert(data);
                        }
            });
```

Here id is your form id.try this very easy you can do